# интерфейс должен быть инициализирован

Tags: kotlin

пробую учить kotlin. Вот код.

```
val url = URL(query)
val protocol = url.protocol
val conn : interface_web

when ( protocol ) {
    "http" -> conn = conn_http()
    "https" -> conn = conn_https()
    else -> WWW_ERRORS.NOT_FOUND_PROTOCOL
}

conn.connect(url)
```

пишет `Variable 'conn' must be initialized`

Comment: что будет в conn, если выполнилась `else ->` ветка?

Comment: @IR42 в таком случае функция вернет ошибку WWW_ERRORS

Comment: как она её вернёт? я не вижу никакого возврата из функции в `else`, да и `WWW_ERRORS.NOT_FOUND_PROTOCOL` не похоже на вызов функции, которая могла бы кидать исключение

Answer (score 4):

Собственно пишет что вы должны задать изначальное значение, например `var conn : interface_web = conn_http()` или же в вашем примере можно сделать так

```
val url = URL(query)
val protocol = url.protocol
var conn : interface_web? = null

when ( protocol ) {
    "http" -> conn = conn_http()
    "https" -> conn = conn_https()
    else -> WWW_ERRORS.NOT_FOUND_PROTOCOL
}

conn?.connect(url)
```

Comment: Это же Котлин! `conn?.connect(url)` и никаких `if`